# No visible @interface for 'SCLFlicManager' declares the selector 'requestButtonFromFlicAppWithCallback:'

Tags: ios, xcode

I have an error for developing flic iOS app.
value of `SCLFlicManager` has no member `requestButtonFromFLicAppWithCallBack`.
Can anybody send me sample app for flic .How to configure flic functionality within our apps? please help

I read and followed [tutorial](https://flic.io/partners/developers/ios-tutorial), but it giving me error that `SCLFLicManager` has not that methods . So I think is `SDK` wrong? Because methods which are used in that tutorial are not there in header files. So What I have to do?
I attached screenshot of my apps

Comment: I also has this error. Create this sample app in swift then it will work.

Comment: I sent you my simple app.